# How do I use Def Function strings in maya

Tags: python, string, maya, function

I've been transposing from mel and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction with this.
I'm not too sure how to run a Function with a specific arg in mind.

```
def testFUNCTION(field):
    if field == 'option1': print 'You have selected option 1'
    else: print 'You have selected option 2'

mc.window( w=150 )
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 1', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=('testFUNCTION, option1'))
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 2', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=('testFUNCTION, option2'))
mc.showWindow()
```

I keep getting:

```
line 1: name 'option1' is not defined
```

Any advise would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create the callback from a string when you pass

```
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 1', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=('testFUNCTION, option1')
```

When the string is evaluated by Maya, 'option1' is not quoted so Python thinks its a variable name.

In general you don't want to use the string format for callbacks for precisely this reason: there will be problems figuring out where variables are defined.

The usual workarounds are to use the `functools` module or a lambda to create callbacks which have all the information they need when they are created.  For example:

```
def testFUNCTION(field):
    if field == 'option1': print 'You have selected option 1'
    else: print 'You have selected option 2'

window = mc.window( w=150 )
mc.columnLayout()
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 1', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=(lambda : testFunction('option1'))
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 2', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=(lambda : testFunction('option2'))
mc.showWindow(window)
```

There's a more detailed explanation of how to set up callbacks easily [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html).

PS: Note the addition of the columnLayout command. Without it your controls will lay out on top of eachother

Answer (score 2):

To pass arguments in maya UI with functools :

*command = partial (defName, arg01, arg02)* # any arguments you need

```
from functools import partial

def testFUNCTION(field, *args):
    if field == 'option1': print 'You have selected option 1'
    else: print 'You have selected option 2'

mc.window( w=150 )
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 1', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=partial(testFUNCTION, 'option1'))
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 2', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=partial(testFUNCTION, 'option2'))
mc.showWindow()
```

Comment: Partial is better than Lambda

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I believe your problem here is that your bc (buttonCommand) flag needs to be a function. For one liner functions you can use a [lambda](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/).

```
mc.textFieldButtonGrp (l='option 1', bl='Set', ad3=2, bc=lambda x='option1': testFUNCTION(x))
```

However, in general I would suggest re-evaluating all together and move away from maya cmds and use pymel.

Perhaps something like this would suite your needs.

```
results = pm.confirmDialog(title='Title', message='Here is an example', button=['option1', 'option2'])
testFUNCTION(result)
```

If you need a more robust GUI, consider experimenting with [PySide](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-SDK/files/GUID-3F96AF53-A47E-4351-A86A-396E7BFD6665-htm.html).