# Maya Python - How to Call Function Using cmds.expression()

Tags: python, expression, maya

My current project requires that I call a particular class function whenever the timeline is scrubbed or selected (per frame, basically). I have tested the use of `cmds.expression(s = 'print "hello "')` and found that, every time I moused over a different frame while scrubbing the timeline, it printed `"hello "` just as I expected. However, whenever I tried to call a class function (or any other defined function for that matter), I receive errors. Here is a general synopsis of my code:

```
class DummyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Dummy'

    def displayName():
        print self.name

d = DummyClass()
cmds.expression(s = 'd.displayName()')
```

I receive the error: `# Error: line 0: Cannot find procedure "d.displayName". #`

And this is a general synopsis of me trying to see whether or not I could call any function definition, let alone a class:

```
def foo():
    print 'Success!'

cmds.expression(s = 'foo()')
```

I receive the error: `# NameError: name 'foo' is not defined #`

Maybe I just don't understand what `cmds.expression()` truly does. Will it only work with external python files or something? I can get `cmds.expression(s = 'print "hello "')` to work, but nothing else within the same script can be found, apparently. Am I taking the wrong approach? Am I missing syntax? I have spent many hours doing research on the matter and have gotten nowhere.

How do I call a defined function, from within a class or otherwise, using `cmds.expression`? If that's not possible, is there a similar command that can do the trick?

Comment: `cmds.expression` creates an expression node.  The text in that node is a subset of regular MEL commands -- not python!.  You can read up on what the expression nodes do here:   https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-5F75516C-403A-4CC3-A118-AEDEFDE970B4-htm.html

In general you only want to use expressions for controlling animation attributes. Otherwise they tend to slow you maya scene way down.

Answer (score 1):

Flag `s` sets the expression string. This type of expression is undoable, queryable and editable.

You should use it this way:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
mc.expression( s = 'pSphere1.translateX = cos(time/2)*10' )
```

But calling Python defined functions you can the same way as described in SO post:

[How do I use Def Function strings in maya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021598/how-do-i-use-def-function-strings-in-maya)